# Mouse config w/ Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, mouse

I have a **Razer DeathAdder 2013** and it has the mouse 4 and 5 buttons on the side. I use them to use voice chat clients like Ventrilo and Mumbl and would prefer that they didn't perform page navigation functions inside Google Chrome. I don't want to just disable them, but I want them to only not do page navigation. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that with Razer Synapse 2.0, it's possible to configure particular mouse behaviour for each program. You could try changing what the buttons do inside Synapse, and hopefully that will solve the problem.

Comment: This was installed automatically and I never touched it until now. It's a pretty cool utility.